# How can i avoid conflict in calendar application of sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I create an **calendar application in sharepoint online** . 
My question is : when I create 2 event with the same date and same time, the 2 is displayed: is there a solution to catch me when I create the 2nd event

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup function from your list compared to your input date, to check is the date `null` or `("")`, if it is null then you can submit it.